# Depth First Algorithm from starting point

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, graph-theory, depth-first-search

Ok, I've looked around a lot online and it's just not clicking with me really.

I have an ArrayList `towns = new ArrayList<Town>` with the towns I'll be performing the DFS on.

I fill this Array with ~8 towns

I have an integer `int i` (index of town in ArrayList which **has** to be first in the path)

I have an initial distance `double dist = 0`

I have a function `distBetween(Town a, Town b)` which does what it says.

I have an Arraylist `route = new ArrayList<Town>()` which contains the order of the towns, depending on the path I'm taking.

Now I have the main function (recursive, according to online research) which performs the Depth-First Search.

```
public static void dfs(){

    // what goes here

}
```

I need to add towns to the route array, and remove them according to the depth first search algorithm. And I need to edit the `dist` variable too.

How would I got about this. Could someone provide me maybe with some pseudo-code or comments just explaining what to do. I can't seem to apply other algorithms I found online. If I could get an explanation specific to my situation that would be great.

I can remove the index `i` from `town` if it makes it easier to perform the search.

Comment: What is your code supposed to do while/after visiting all paths? Are you trying to find the path with the minimum total distance?

Comment: minimize total distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you have a `State` class with the following attributes (if you like graphs, use `Node` instead of `State`):

```
Set<Town> unused;        // towns not yet visited
ArrayList<Town> path;    // current path
double dist;             // total distance in path
```

Then use code like this one to recursively try out every single possible path using DFS. On the first call, use `dfs(emptyState, startTown, null)`:

```
public static void dfs(State s, Town last, State best) {
    s.path.add(last);
    s.unused.remove(last);
    if (unused.empty()) {
        // all towns visited - distance and path are now complete
        if (best == null || s.dist < best.dist) best = s;
        return;
    }
    for (Town t : s.unused) {
        State next = s.copy(); // a copy of State s
        next.dist += distBetween(last, t);
        dfs(next, t);
    }
}
```

After calling this function, all paths will have been visited exactly once (in DFS order), and `best` will contain the shortest one. Beware, for many cities this becomes very slow - O(n!).

Comment: Thanks so much! I realise its O(n!), I will be performing this on small clusters of Towns (<9)

Answer (score 1):

**DFS Algorithm**

1. Input the vertices and edges of the graph G = (V, E).
2. Input the source vertex and assign it to the variable S.
3. Push the source vertex to the stack.
4. Repeat the steps 5 and 6 until the stack is empty.
5. Pop the top element of the stack and display it.
6. Push the vertices which is neighbor to just popped element, if it is not in the queue and displayed (ie; not visited).
7. Exit.

To store the vertices and the edges you will need an [adjacency matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AdjacencyMatrix.html).

Comment: I have an adjacency matrix. That's what I access when running the `distbetween()` function. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Generally in TSP, all towns are connected to all towns. In step 6, a set is better than checking if it is in a queue or not.